# How to change bower's default components folder?

Tags: node.js, bower

I'm making a new project that uses bower from twitter. I created a `component.json` to maintain all my dependency like jquery. Then I run `bower install` that installs everything in a folder named `components`. But I need to install the components in a different folder, e.g. `public/components`.

I have tried editing my components.json into:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "directory": "public/",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "*"
  }
}
```

or:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "componentsDirectory": "public/",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "*"
  }
}
```

as shown in https://github.com/twitter/bower/pull/94 but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 931, accepted):

Create a [Bower configuration file `.bowerrc`](http://bower.io/docs/config/) in the project root (as opposed to your home directory) with the content:

```
{
  "directory" : "public/components"
}
```

Run `bower install` again.

Comment: I changelog I can only see `The value of the json property from .bowerrc is no longer used` and I guess everything is OK with `"directory"` property. Right? https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Right. You just have to add it in `bower.json`.  
[Current specification of `bower.json` format](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1APq7oA9tNao1UYWyOm8dKqlRP2blVkROYLZ2fLIjtWc/edit#heading=h.9obwb54illsh)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Works in .bowerrc, but not bower.json. This seems like such a basic feature...

Comment: I am curious as to why this wouldn't be put in the bower.json file. Especially if it is a per project setting anyways.

Comment: Based on the docs, it has to be in .bowerrc, not bower.json. Strange ... http://bower.io/#custom-install-directory

Comment: Wasn't working for me until I realized I hadn't even created a bower.json file yet.. then it worked fine.

Comment: FYI, use `echo "" > .bowerrc` to create this file in Windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20202202/how-do-i-name-the-bowerrc-file

Comment: In Windows, to create a file that starts with ".", simply create the file with a trailing ".". In other words, just call it ".bowerrc."

Comment: I'm packaging a web app that will require installing specific bower components into a specific path. I will need to include a `.bowerrc` file, because that is the only place where the **directory** config is honored. I will also need to include a `bower.json` because that is the only place where I can specify **dependencies**. Hence, both files are required when creating a package. That's a little silly.

Comment: yeah its completely freaking ridiculous that it can't go in bower.json. The concept that you should dirty up your root directory for a *package manager* is maddening. Sigh. But I'm giving it a go anyways (despite this being like the 10th project I've used Bower on, I still am  not really seeing a ton of benefit to using it).

Comment: Is there a way to have a default directory, but then send a single dependency to another directory? Perhaps: "dependencies": { "special": { source: "http...git", directory: "./special-tools" } }

Comment: I think it needs a leading slash at the end (`public/components/`)

Answer (score 77):

In addition to editing `.bowerrc` to setup your default install path, you can also setup custom install paths for different file types.

There is a node package called [bower-installer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bower-installer) that provides a single command for managing alternate install paths.

run `npm install -g bower-installer`

Set up your bower.json

```
{
  "name" : "test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "dependencies" : {
    "jquery-ui" : "latest"
  },
  "install" : {
    "path" : {
      "css": "src/css",
      "js": "src/js"
    },
    "sources" : {
      "jquery-ui" : [
        "components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.custom.js",
        "components/jquery-ui/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Run the following command: `bower-installer`

This will install `components/jquery-ui/themes/start/jquery-ui.css` to `./src/css`, etc

Comment: This looks promising but the `bower_components` directory is still created  and populated. :(

Comment: what version of bower?

Comment: appears to be the nature of the package. you could open an issue here http://github.com/blittle/bower-installer/issues/ or write a bash script to remove the directory post install.

Comment: I think there is no sense. I don't want package which still downloads full git repo and dependencies and then just copypastes specific files for me... I can press Ctrl+C myself. I hoped it will download only specific files for me.

Comment: yeah I hear you. in this case I just a .bowerrc and point to public/bower or public/vendor to keep the project simple.

Comment: @Alendorff You can run `bower-installer --remove`. It will remove the `bower_components` directory after installation.

Comment: Is it possible to user .bowerrc and bower-installer so that bower-installer will get the path of bower_components?

Answer (score 64):

I had the same issue on my windows 10. This is what fixed my problem

1. Delete `bower_components` in your root folder
2. Create a `.bowerrc` file in the root
3. In the file write this code `{"directory" : "public/bower_components"}`
4. Run a `bower install`

You should see bower_components folder in your public folder now

Answer (score 24):

### Something worth mentioning...

As noted above by other contributors, using a `.bowerrc` file with the JSON

`{ "directory": "some/path" }`

is necessary -- HOWEVER, you may run into an issue on Windows while creating that file. If Windows gives you a message imploring you to add a "*file name*", simply use a text editor / IDE such as Notepad++.

Add the JSON to an unnamed file, save it as *.bowerrc* -- you're good to go!

Probably an easy assumption, but I hope this save others the unnecessary headache :)

Comment: In Windows, to create a file that starts with ".", simply create the file with a trailing ".". In other words, just call it ".bowerrc."

Comment: you can do it with git bash too, simply type: ```echo >> .bowerrc```

Answer (score 7):

Try putting the `components.json` file in the `public` directory of your application, rather than the root directory, then re-run `bower install` ...try this in your app home directory:

```
cp components.json public
cd public
bower install
```

Comment: yup that can be a way, is there a legit way to do it? but ill still count this as an answer.

Comment: you could write a bash script `bower.sh` to prepend the directory you want to install to, like `public-components.json' then it would generate the above commands..

Comment: Both of those answers sound super hacky, definitely not desirable

Answer (score -3):

Hi i am same problem and resolve this ways.

windows user and vs cant'create .bowerrc file.

in cmd go any folder

install any packages which is contains .bowerrc file forexample

```
bower install angular-local-storage
```

this plugin contains .bowerrc file. copy that and go to your project and paste this file.

and in visual studio - solution explorer - show all files and include project 
seen .bowerrc file

i resolve this ways :)

Comment: you can use `Cygwin` or `Cmder` terminal to create `.bowerrc` file.

Comment: Just create the file with any name, then open up a PowerShell or Command Prompt and rename it.

Comment: You can create a dot file in windows by specifying the filename as '.name.' - still not many people know this after so many years of this being available :)