# Choose bower install directory

Tags: bower

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14079833/759866). I'm using bower 0.7.1, and still cannot get the components to be installed anywhere else than in the `components` folder.

I tried adding the following line to my `component.json`, as per [this PR](https://github.com/twitter/bower/pull/94):

```
"componentsDirectory": "public/components"
```

But it will still install in `./components`.

I tried to create a `.bowerrc` file next to `component.json`:

```
{
  "directory" : "public/components"
}
```

But I get this error when running `bower install`:

> Error: Unable to parse local .bowerrc file: Unexpected token }

Any idea?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Actually the .bowerrc file does work, this was an issue with my IDE not saving the file properly:

```
{
  "directory" : "public/components"
}
```

I'm still wondering why `componentsDirectory` still doesn't work in `component.json`, though.

Comment: Also, you can add a .bowerrc to your project, not just your home folder :)

Comment: See [Custom install directory](http://bower.io/#custom-install-directory) documentation

Comment: @GabLeRoux this documentation does not exist

Comment: They updated their website and removed the snippet (­[proof](http://web.archive.org/web/20140604013505/http://bower.io/#custom-install-directory)) We can still have details on the `directory` parameter on the [.bowerrc specification page](http://bower.io/docs/config/#directory). Note: Internet is not a constant ;)

Comment: Is there a way to have a default directory, but then send a single dependency to another directory? Perhaps: "dependencies": { "special": { source: "http...git", directory: "./special-tools" } }

Comment: @Cody I have no idea, you should create a new question!

Answer (score 18):

While you can happily use Bower to manage the dependencies of your own personal projects, primarily the `component.json` is a description of your project *for other people*. If you share a component through the Bower registry the `component.json` goes with it to describe the dependencies. That is why your own *local* preferences like where to install components don't belong in there.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to change installation directory temporarily is using `--config` option in command line:

`bower install jquery --config.directory=/path/to/your/components`

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating this file in Notepad++, make sure the Encoding is set to "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" and save as file type "Any".