# derby.js client side scripts and where to put stylesheets

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an application that I have already built the front end for the client side originally in HTML,CSS,JS,and Jquery . I am now trying to build it with derbyjs but I do not know where to put my custom JS scripts, scripts that I linked to my HTML like jquery and bootstrap, or my CSS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see derby file structure documentation http://derbyjs.com/#file_structure

Derby include your css files automaticly, but you have to convert them into .styl see http://derbyjs.com/#stylesheets or use @import statment see http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/import.html

for js files please see [Including JS files in Derby.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776922/including-js-files-in-derby-js)