# Bower - how to download packages another folder instead the folder where the bower.json is there

Tags: bower

I initialized a bower project under d:\myProject and if i run `bower install angularjs` the packages are copy in the same folder. But what i need to do is to copy the packages under d:\myprojects\src\resources\static. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower's [docs](http://bower.io/docs/config/) tell you that adding the `"directory"` tag in your `.bowerrc` file will make bower put downloaded packages in that dir.

notice that the path is relative to where you have the project's json so in your case:

```
{
  "directory": "src/resources/static/"
  ...
}
```

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042570/choose-bower-install-directory) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079833/how-to-change-bowers-default-components-folder).