# Where should I put bower.json?

Tags: javascript, npm, bower

So, I'm using bower 1.2.2 to manage my client side libraries for the first time. My app is a simple node app, and I can't decide where to initialize bower. Here's my file structure:

```
|____gruntfile.js
|____package.json
|____server.js
|____static
| |____index.html
```

Should I initialize bower in the root next to gruntfile.js and package.json, or should I do it in my static directory. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is mostly up to you. Though, to have your `bower.json` and the install directory in different locations, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14080568.

Comment: Thanks! directory: '/static/components' is what I was after.

Comment: It should still be available, just to a different file. You'll need a `.bowerrc` as the link briefly mentions.

Comment: To further clarify, .bowerrc was where I specified the directory I wanted components to be installed in.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you can have that on the root where other tasks files are added. This way your bower_components will also reside on the root folder along with node_modules.