# cannot change bower components folder

Tags: bower, package-managers

I'm trying to override bower's component folder following the answers in this question: [How to change bower's default components folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079833/how-to-change-bowers-default-components-folder)

this is my bower.json file (with all the things I've tried)

```
{
  "name": "sample-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "directory": "public/libs/",
  "componentsDirectory": "public/libs/",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "latest"
  }
}
```

and this is my .bowerrc:

```
{
  "directory": "public/libs/",
  "componentsDirectory": "public/libs/"
}
```

I've tried a couple more things, but the settings just seems to be ignored, and the components are installed to bower_components

these are the versions I'm using:

```
$ bower -v
1.2.8
$ npm -v
1.3.24
$ node -v
v0.10.25
```

Comment: I've tried this multiple times, and it always succeeds for me.

Comment: thanks for the comment, Kelly, what configuration did you use? do you have some github working sample I can download and try myself?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code above exactly.  Not sure why it's not working for you :0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a [github](https://github.com/kellyjandrews/bower-demo) of this working.  It's not the identical code you have above, but if you can get this to work, you should be able to iterate from there.

Comment: gee, I've compared my project with yours, and found a shameless typo (a space in front of the .bowerrc file)... I'm so embarrassed, thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Bower on Windows, you should make sure that you have selected Run **Git from the Windows Command Prompt**(second option) during GIT Installation. Then it'll work!!

[Refer link here](http://scotch.io/bar-talk/manage-front-end-resources-with-bower?utm_source=feedblitz&utm_medium=FeedBlitzRss&utm_campaign=scotch_io)