# Bower Custom install directory

Tags: bower

Hey I am new to using bower and I am trying to give a custom install directory.

Looking at the documentation I have made a file a.bowerrc and within it has
"{
  "directory": "js/lib"
}"

But when I run bower install it just creates the bower components folder within my main folder

Do I have to place the .bowerrc file somewhere different? or add more to file path?

My file structure is

main -folder
   a.bowerrec -file
   bower.json -file
   js -folder
      lib -folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your filename is "a.bowerrec"? It should be just ".bowerrc", you'll have to rename it.

The file should be placed in your projects root directory with your bower.json file.

You should find this answer for [changing bower's default component directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14080568) useful.

Answer (score 0):

> Example directory = *public/components*
>
> Example package = *jquery*

Either create a dotfile `.bowerrc` and drop in `{"directory": "public/components"}` or use the `bower install` command adding a `--config.directory=public/components` flag.

**To create the dotfile:**

Windows (CLI):

```
echo {"directory": "public/components"} >> .bowerrc
```

Unix:

```
echo '{"directory": "public/components"}' >> .bowerrc
```

**To run directly (both OS's):**

```
bower install --save --config.directory=public/components jquery
```