# Location of bower_components

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, bower

I am trying to use yeoman, grunt and bower for my AngularJS development on Windows 7. I am using GitBash to run the commands. I did the following steps

1. Installed node.js (npm --version 1.4.14)
2. npm install -g yeoman grunt-cli bower
3. npm install -g generator-angular
4. cd c:/wamp/www
5. mkdir test-ang
6. cd test-ang
7. yo angular

When the scaffolding process is complete, I always find that my bower_components folder is outside app. Due to this my index.html is displayed without any styles and javascript as they link to "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css". same thing happends for js files too. If I change it to ../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" in index.html, then things look fine. But doing grunt serve changes the index.html again

I tried to manually move bower_components inside app folder and edit .bowerrc file accordingly, but it did not help either. Also another interesting thing is, if I do the above listed steps in Virtual box ( running CentOs ) at my work machine, then the bower_components folder is automatically inside app folder.

Has anyone faced this before? Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Comment: take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14080568/1163411. PS: You should not move the folder manually!

Comment: thanks Ivica. i followed your instructions and the bower_components folder got created inside app. I assume I could delete the original bower_components folder. But I am noticing one more issue now after doing grunt serve. The paths on index.html look like bower_componenbootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css instead of the expected bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css which breaks the style and js. Is the path getting trimmed somewhere in the code?