# Bower registering packages to be downloaded in same directory

Tags: package, structure, bower, directory-structure, bower-register

I am looking to do something but am not sure if its possible.

I am registering several packages with bower all of which are of the same "package".

What i want to do:

I have 3 packages called child-1, child-2 and child-3 which I have registered with bower.

How can I manage to structure of is there any option to activate so that all of my packages gets donwloaded in the same directory e.g : bower_components/parent/

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can only edit your project `bower.json`.

This might be useful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-installer or https://stackoverflow.com/a/21818157/1348344.

In particular:

```
{
  "install" : {
        "path" : "some/path",
        "sources" : {
            "child-1" : "components/parent"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it is not exactly what i wanted to do. I wanted all the plugins of a framework which i am building to be installed in one folder instead of having them in different folders. when others download it. I tried setting the name of the plugin to a path name in the bower.json before registering it but does not work